# in flex, is it possible to embed speex files?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, speex

Flash 10 supposedly has support for the Speex audio format.  I'd like to embed some Speex files in my SWF:

```
[Embed(source='assets/test.spx',mimeType='audio/x-speex')]
private static const SpeexSound:Class;
```

However, I get the error:

```
no transcoder registered for mimeType 'audio/x-speex'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been researching this some more.  Here are the options:

1. Embed an ogg speex file and use an Alchemy-compiled libOgg and libSpeex to decode it.  The decoded bytes can be fed into Flash via [SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html).  Its painfully ironic that Alchemy has to be used, when we *know* that libSpeex lives in the Flash Player somewhere.
2. You can't embed FLVs, but you can embed SWFs, so convert a Speex FLV into a Speex SWF.  The conversion can be done with ffmpeg like this:

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i test-with-speex.flv -vn test.swf
   ```

   However, that will unfortunately auto-convert the audio into MP3 inside the SWF.  You *should* be able to preserve the codec like this

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i test-with-speex.flv -vn -acodec libspeex test.swf
   ```

   but ffmpeg doesn't currently support non-MP3 SWFs.  Grr.  Perhaps there's other conversion tools that will do it?

Answer (score 1):

Speex is not a real transport format -- it has no framing built into the protocol, so it is typically wrapped in an OGG stream (whose API is unfortunately more complicated than the Speex API itself, but I digress...) So "audio/x-speex" really means "Speex in OGG".

I haven't seen anywhere that Flash supports OGG -- so those files you get from `speexenc` aren't going to work :(

Reportedly Flash encodes/decodes Speex in FLV format (according to this page: http://jira.red5.org/confluence/display/codecs/Speex+Codec). I haven't tried this because I want to target Flash 9 (maybe ffmpeg would encode correctly with some fiddling) but let me know if you get anywhere with this.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't seem that we can embed FLV files.  :/

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, you can use this tricked-out ffmpeg project:

http://code.google.com/p/xuggle-ffmpeg/

And encode your audio something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -acodec libspeex -f flv -y speex.flv
```